# Toast message to specify the numbers that the messages were sent to

Tags: android, sms

So I am almost done with the `SMS` functionality with my application. The last thing it needs to do is to display a `Toast` to which numbers it sent the messages to.
I have the following code:

**Global Variables:**

```
private BroadcastReceiver sendBroadcastReceiver;
private BroadcastReceiver deliveryBroadcastReceiver;

String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";
```

**Declared on void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState):**

```
sendBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
        {

            public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1)
            {
                switch (getResultCode())
                {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS Sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Generic failure", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No service", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Null PDU", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Radio off", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                }
            }
        };

        deliveryBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
        {
            public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1)
            {
                switch (getResultCode())
                {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS Delivered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS not delivered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                }
            }
        };
    registerReceiver(deliveryBroadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));
    registerReceiver(sendBroadcastReceiver , new IntentFilter(SENT));
```

**The send SMS function:**

```
private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message)
{        
    String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
    String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";
    PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(SENT), 0);
    PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);
    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentPI, deliveredPI); 
}
```

**Calling the contacts(stored in preferences) to method call:**

```
ArrayList<String> contacts = new ArrayList();

List<String> list = SM.getAllValue();
    for(String string : list){
        contacts.add(string);
        }
    for(int i = 0; i < contacts.size(); i++){
        String numberToSend = contacts.get(i).toString();
        sendSMS(numberToSend, sms);
    }
```

Where `SM.getAllValue()` returns the `list` of user's contacts.

**Finally onStop()**

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    unregisterReceiver(sendBroadcastReceiver);
    unregisterReceiver(deliveryBroadcastReceiver);
    super.onStop();

}
```

On sending messages to multiple numbers, the following code gives me a `SMS Sent` toast over and over again. How can I now specify numbers within the toast like `SMS Sent to Number1`, `SMS sent to Number2` etc. or collectively say that `All the SMS's were delivered`.
Please help :)

Answer (score 1):

In the sent broadcast intent (`new Intent(SENT)`), you can add the number to which you send it :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(SENT);
intent.putExtra("number", phoneNumber);
PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);
```

then in your receiver, you can use the number :

```
public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
    String phoneNumber = arg1.getStringExtra("number");
    // Use it in the toast
}
```

Comment: I am just getting the 1st number from the preferences.

Comment: `SM.getAllValues()` gives returns all the values that the users have saved as their android preference in form of a list.

Comment: i don't see how that is related to the answer i gave?

Comment: ... the answer you gave ... loops through the last number ... like if i have num1, num2 and num3. The toast rather then giving me ... Message sent to num1, Message sent to num2, Message sent to num3 gives me Message sent to num3 (x3).

Comment: shouldn't. the answer I gave includes the number to which you sent the sms in the intent that notifies you that the message has been sent. therefore, the toast should display the exact same number as the one the message was sent to.

Answer (score 0):

first in here add a new variable

```
String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";
```

name it `String name = null;`

then under    `String numberToSend = contacts.get(i).toString();`

add `name = numberToSend;`

now in the toast add the variable

```
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS to " + name + " has been sent.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

**update:**

first remove your every contact toast

```
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS Sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

I prefer making it a  `Log.e("fd","Fddf");`

then in the loop add an if statement.

```
    for(int i = 0; i < contacts.size(); i++){
if (i = contacts.size(){
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS Sent to all contacts.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}else {
        String numberToSend = contacts.get(i).toString();
        sendSMS(numberToSend, sms);
}
    }
```

Comment: using this gave me the last `numberToSend` on each toast generated.

Comment: isn't that what you want ? sms sent to 96955995 ?

Comment: yes ... but I also wanted to show the remaining numbers too ... like if I had num1, num2 and num3, I'd like all the numbers to come up in the toast. the current code gives only num3.

Comment: so you want a toast like this .. sms sent to xx1,xx2,xx3,xx4,xx5 ?

Comment: that or individually, the messages are to have been sent though.